# reading only certain keys from dictionary in binary file python

Tags: python, binaryfiles

So I'm writing a dictionary to a binary file (below), but what I'd like to know if that when we use pickled to load data - is it possible to load just a portion of the file (rather than the whole one ea time?)

```
import pickle

# write python dict to a file
dct = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
fi = open('myfile.pkl', 'wb')
pickle.dump(dct, fi)
fi.close()

# read python dict back from the file
pkl_fi = open('myfile.pkl', 'rb')
res_dct = pickle.load(pkl_fi)
pkl_fi.close()
print (res_dct)
```

As expected, if I print out the result from pickle load:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

How would I achieve an output of just a dictionary with 'a' and 'b' keys?

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}  # desired output
```

Comment: No, it is not possible to load a pickled object partially or change a pickled object without first loading it.

Comment: @DYZ as a follow-up question , is possible to use 'ab' to keep updating the file? eg. if im using a loop and want to keep using dct.update({k:v}) to the file

Comment: You can write update versions into the file, but they will not overwrite the previously saved versions.

Comment: @DYZ could you write a simple example of using a for loop to update a dictionary inside a bin file?

Comment: As I said, this would not be possible. I said 'you could write updated versions' (just like you would write the original version), not 'update the dictionary'.